# use HTML in JSON in multi language i18next nextJs website

Tags: html, reactjs, json, next.js

i have multi-language next js website.

i use packge i18next. i define variable in jsx like this.

```
{t("satisfied:title")}
```

it means

```
{t("JSONflieName:JSONvariable")}
```

but in json file i can't use HTML and it shows me like string

```
"title" : "this is my<br \/> <span class=\"test\"> test <\/span> title"
```

Comment: The "t" function is not part of NextJS. And your question doesn't seem to be related to NextJS at all. Please make sure to post, what library you're using for translations. I would guess that it is `react-i18next`?

Comment: yes, that's true. sorry for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML entities are escaped for security reasons by React. In order to make your translations render actual HTML you could do something like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t("satisfied:title")}} />
```

But, I would strongly advice you to **not** do it like above. The actual thing you should beware of is putting HTML into your translated texts. If these translations are managed at some point by external translators, they might not be familiar with the HTML syntax. Do you trust these translators to not destroy your UI accidentally? You should not.

Instead you should use the advanced concepts for handling cases like above using this technique: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component